# What is the meaning of Cassandra's vision of Lex in "Smallvillle" S01E06?

Tags: dc, smallville

In *Smallville* S01E06, when Lex finally decides to learn his future, Cassandra sees him being the President of the United States, he's wearing a white costume. Then he walks out of the building, appears in the sunflower field with all the sunflowers dying as soon as he touches the first one. After the sunflowers are gone, a field of skeletons emerges from beneath and a blood rain starts.

While it's obvious that Lex Luthor is the main antagonist for Superman, why so many cryptic elements? Yes, he kills lots of people, hence the blood, but what's the meaning of being the President, sunflowers and even a rain of blood?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't seen the show for a long time but the symbols are clear:

1. **Lex president**: This symbolizes Lex's ambition. The reason he came to see Cassandra is because he believes he has a destiny to fulfill

> Lex: Signs I don't want to ignore.
>
> Cassandra: what kind of signs
>
> Lex: I live when I should have died. (...)

IIRC, at that point in the series, Lex is still well-intentioned, albeit overly confident in his talent and with a "the end justifies the means" attitude.

> Lex: I don't want to do good things, I want to do great things.

This is also a nod to the comics where Lex Luthor actually becomes President of the United States:

[image: Lex Luthor President]

Apparently, he had been president at least four times (see [here](https://www.denofgeek.com/us/books-comics/superman/260081/lex-luthor-and-the-three-times-he-was-elected-us-president) or [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6at9f.jpg) - thanks Jenaya for the second link) in the comics and animated series.

2. **Crops** represent America, especially rural America. Superman has always represented the countryside through the Kent as something intrinsically good.
3. As you guessed, **dead bodies** and **blood** represent the damages caused by Lex Luthor.

In short, the ambition (President) of Lex Luthor will bring death (blood and corpses) and destruction (rotten crops) to America.

Comment: Four times. He's president in the Justice League/Power Rangers crossover as well, see [this bill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6at9f.jpg)

Comment: @Jenaya: edited! Thanks